# cannot connect to ssh server over private network

Tags: networking

Private network at hotel starts with 10 DOT

ssh worked **yesterday** but now it does not but something changed apparently.

I did lsof and netstat and ports are open.
I can ssh from localhost too.

Computer1: 10.181.121.131
Computer2: 10.181.123.171 (**notice difference between 121 and 123** )

*TCPdump* is showing TCP traffic as well. Can post this as well

```
ssh -vvv ubuntu@10.180.123.171
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.180.123.171 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.180.123.171 [10.180.123.171] port 22. 
debug1: connect to address 10.180.123.171 port 22: Operation timed out 
ssh: connect to host 10.180.123.171 port 22: Operation timed out
```

**ip addr show**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:34:cd:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:70:5a:76:db:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.180.123.171/22 brd 10.180.123.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 3464sec preferred_lft 3464sec
    inet6 fe80::e46e:7819:19e8:535f/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

**tcpdump**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo tcpdump -vv -i wlp2s0 | grep -vi udp
tcpdump: listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
07:12:21.862029 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42303, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48208 > 185.199.110.154.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x8a41 (correct), seq 1742715447, ack 444025959, win 1316, options [nop,nop,TS val 1128615790 ecr 395724620], length 0
07:12:21.862075 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41014, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48960 > 199.232.36.133.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x3319 (correct), seq 2527509201, ack 2876257345, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2785638799 ecr 111720059], length 0
07:12:21.864199 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 4212, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    185.199.110.154.https > ubuntu.48208: Flags [.], cksum 0xc8f9 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 67, options [nop,nop,TS val 395735884 ecr 1128524183], length 0
07:12:21.876428 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 40596, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    199.232.36.133.https > ubuntu.48960: Flags [.], cksum 0x6e74 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 61, options [nop,nop,TS val 111731322 ecr 2785547245], length 0
07:12:22.641254 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:23.910091 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17921, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.37550 > 172.253.122.188.5228: Flags [.], cksum 0xdbbc (correct), seq 2154171282, ack 1718016291, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 74887899 ecr 1303212886], length 0
07:12:23.928688 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 109, id 50411, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.253.122.188.5228 > ubuntu.37550: Flags [.], cksum 0x1091 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 253, options [nop,nop,TS val 1303257942 ecr 74436356], length 0
07:12:24.654755 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:25.958009 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20657, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48214 > 185.199.110.154.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xe3c0 (correct), seq 1063931252, ack 626098066, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1128619886 ecr 717890805], length 0
07:12:25.958036 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22089, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48966 > 199.232.36.133.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x3e7c (correct), seq 2305774199, ack 16525755, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2785642895 ecr 67881019], length 0
07:12:25.960299 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 34420, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    185.199.110.154.https > ubuntu.48214: Flags [.], cksum 0x1b17 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 59, options [nop,nop,TS val 717902068 ecr 1128529363], length 0
07:12:25.974626 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 35846, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    199.232.36.133.https > ubuntu.48966: Flags [.], cksum 0x7517 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 62, options [nop,nop,TS val 67892282 ecr 2785552556], length 0
07:12:26.671519 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:28.684705 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
          Client-Ethernet-Address 4c:5e:0c:25:89:fb (oui Unknown)
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 4c:5e:0c:25:89:fb
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 6:
              Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server, Domain-Name
              Netbios-Name-Server, Static-Route
07:12:30.697528 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:32.710694 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:34.723560 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:35.942034 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2394, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.37754 > lb-192-30-253-117-iad.github.com.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x433e (correct), seq 3907856818, ack 2369539295, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3674991291 ecr 611156336], length 0
07:12:35.962975 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 61066, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    lb-192-30-253-117-iad.github.com.https > ubuntu.37754: Flags [R], cksum 0xfc9b (correct), seq 2369539295, win 0, length 0
07:12:36.736934 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:38.749707 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:40.294013 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34073, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.60608 > a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x74db (correct), seq 2031889910, ack 287213254, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4177741219 ecr 1101782835], length 0
07:12:40.308687 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 56, id 2119, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https > ubuntu.60608: Flags [.], cksum 0xe404 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 1708, options [nop,nop,TS val 1101827890 ecr 4177469894], length 0
07:12:40.550002 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 28884, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.35168 > lb-192-30-253-118-iad.github.com.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xe294 (correct), seq 1149792290, ack 2934872670, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 3847708108 ecr 608198087], length 0
07:12:40.570499 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 1168, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    lb-192-30-253-118-iad.github.com.https > ubuntu.35168: Flags [R], cksum 0x9783 (correct), seq 2934872670, win 0, length 0
07:12:40.764036 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:42.776832 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:44.789997 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:45.414002 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell ubuntu, length 28
07:12:45.415016 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply _gateway is-at 4c:5e:0c:25:89:fb (oui Unknown), length 46
07:12:46.803013 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:48.816151 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:50.830696 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:52.842666 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:54.630014 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32553, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.45698 > 162.248.19.151.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x315f (correct), seq 4187733252, ack 2737010065, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1541400763 ecr 1516299243], length 0
07:12:54.630046 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59154, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.60296 > a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x1233 (correct), seq 1665573797, ack 279120259, win 5050, options [nop,nop,TS val 4177755555 ecr 1101797171], length 0
07:12:54.644442 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 248, id 42629, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    162.248.19.151.https > ubuntu.45698: Flags [.], cksum 0x7f4e (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 14494, options [nop,nop,TS val 1516344298 ecr 1540994088], length 0
07:12:54.644463 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 56, id 58009, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https > ubuntu.60296: Flags [.], cksum 0xa925 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 336, options [nop,nop,TS val 1101842226 ecr 4177348896], length 0
07:12:54.856323 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:56.875522 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:12:58.888403 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:00.901939 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:02.915154 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:03.878928 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.180.123.68 tell _gateway, length 46
07:13:04.928775 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:06.918016 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41015, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48960 > 199.232.36.133.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x5719 (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2785683855 ecr 111731322], length 0
07:13:06.918067 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42304, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48208 > 185.199.110.154.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xae40 (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 1316, options [nop,nop,TS val 1128660846 ecr 395735884], length 0
07:13:06.920894 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 4213, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    185.199.110.154.https > ubuntu.48208: Flags [.], cksum 0x9cf9 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 67, options [nop,nop,TS val 395747148 ecr 1128524183], length 0
07:13:06.932330 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 40597, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    199.232.36.133.https > ubuntu.48960: Flags [.], cksum 0x4274 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 61, options [nop,nop,TS val 111742586 ecr 2785547245], length 0
07:13:06.941305 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:08.955301 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:08.966018 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17922, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.37550 > 172.253.122.188.5228: Flags [.], cksum 0x7bbb (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 74932955 ecr 1303257942], length 0
07:13:08.984383 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 109, id 5880, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    172.253.122.188.5228 > ubuntu.37550: Flags [.], cksum 0x6090 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 253, options [nop,nop,TS val 1303302998 ecr 74436356], length 0
07:13:10.968437 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:11.014038 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22090, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48966 > 199.232.36.133.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x627c (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2785687951 ecr 67892282], length 0
07:13:11.014072 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20658, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.48214 > 185.199.110.154.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x07c1 (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1128664942 ecr 717902068], length 0
07:13:11.016322 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 34421, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    185.199.110.154.https > ubuntu.48214: Flags [.], cksum 0xef16 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 59, options [nop,nop,TS val 717913332 ecr 1128529363], length 0
07:13:11.028381 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 35847, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    199.232.36.133.https > ubuntu.48966: Flags [.], cksum 0x4917 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 62, options [nop,nop,TS val 67903546 ecr 2785552556], length 0
07:13:12.981521 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:13.547019 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.180.122.34 tell _gateway, length 46
07:13:14.086001 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell ubuntu, length 28
07:13:14.086900 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply _gateway is-at 4c:5e:0c:25:89:fb (oui Unknown), length 46
07:13:14.994675 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:15.477081 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.180.121.98 tell _gateway, length 46
07:13:17.007989 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:19.021232 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:21.034886 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:23.047707 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:25.060972 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:25.350022 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34074, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.60608 > a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https: Flags [.], cksum 0x14db (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4177786275 ecr 1101827890], length 0
07:13:25.364660 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 56, id 2120, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https > ubuntu.60608: Flags [.], cksum 0x3405 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 1708, options [nop,nop,TS val 1101872945 ecr 4177469894], length 0
07:13:27.076993 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:29.090096 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:31.104195 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:33.116795 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:34.458707 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.180.121.94 tell _gateway, length 46
07:13:35.130437 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:37.143385 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
          Client-Ethernet-Address 4c:5e:0c:25:89:fb (oui Unknown)
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether 4c:5e:0c:25:89:fb
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 6:
              Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Domain-Name-Server, Domain-Name
              Netbios-Name-Server, Static-Route
07:13:39.156868 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:39.686011 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59155, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.60296 > a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xb232 (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 5050, options [nop,nop,TS val 4177800611 ecr 1101842226], length 0
07:13:39.686039 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32554, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ubuntu.45698 > 162.248.19.151.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xd15e (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1541445819 ecr 1516344298], length 0
07:13:39.700439 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 56, id 58010, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    a104-81-132-67.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com.https > ubuntu.60296: Flags [.], cksum 0xf925 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 336, options [nop,nop,TS val 1101887281 ecr 4177348896], length 0
07:13:39.700461 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 248, id 8326, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    162.248.19.151.https > ubuntu.45698: Flags [.], cksum 0xcf4d (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 14494, options [nop,nop,TS val 1516389354 ecr 1540994088], length 0
07:13:39.856529 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.180.121.89 tell _gateway, length 46
07:13:40.724560 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10.180.121.76 tell _gateway, length 46
07:13:41.170660 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:43.183163 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:44.806006 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell ubuntu, length 28
07:13:44.806921 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply _gateway is-at 4c:5e:0c:25:89:fb (oui Unknown), length 46
07:13:45.196253 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:47.210247 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:49.222732 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:51.234412 STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Learn, Forward], bridge-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00.8017, length 42
        message-age 0.00s, max-age 20.00s, hello-time 2.00s, forwarding-delay 15.00s
        root-id 801f.00:15:62:af:da:00, root-pathcost 0, port-role Designated
07:13:51.974037 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42305, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
^C223 packets captured
223 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ^C
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If is not clear what you are asking. Are the local computer and the remote computer are in the same 10.180.123.nnn network?

Comment: yes they are the same wifi connection. Bot IPs are similar too 10.180.123.nn

Comment: Do you address it by hostname or by IP?

Comment: Without getting a calculator, you're sowing us Computer 1 with `inet 10.180.123.171/22 brd 10.180.123.255` but not Computer 2, only `10.181.123.171` and on top of this mismatch a complex protocol. 1. does `ping 10.181.123.171` working? Are there **routing entrys** in both ways on the systems or the router/gateway? ... I know similar printer issues, where I was able to reach the printer in a different network over a router, but the it can't answer because there was no route back.

Comment: @LupusE ping is not working. Can you give me the command on the routing entries and I will fetch those for you. Its a hotel router to which I do not have access. However, this **used** to work

Comment: `ip r`will do the trick. In short: You are in a net. The net contains a network address (10.180.**123**.0) a subnet (lets say 24 = `255.255.255.0`) and a broadcast (10.180.**123**.255). Now you can reach every system with any IP from 10.180.**123**.1 to 10.180.**123**.254 just by ethernet-magic ... But to reach any address outside your subnet, you'll need a route. The route says 'if you want to reach 10.180.**121**.x, use the router/gateway/... 10.180.**123**.x (it should be your net, too) - Maybe it is enough to change your subnet to `255.255.0.0` and reach 10.180.0.0 to 10.180.255.254

Comment: Please be aware this is a very complex topic explained with very few words. We only have access to one side and can't configure such things as the broadcast and so on. So there is a lot of try and error (and understand).

Comment: @LupusE my netmask is 255.255.252.0 which makes my  CIDR10.180.120.0/22 and hence both ips are on the same subnet but still cannot talk (nmap, ping, ssh all fail). However, they could talk for **just 1 night** and next morning stopped working. I doubt someone changed a network setting __just__ in the same night. 

To isolate **router**I being the issue, I connected my 2 laptops to a hotspot and they can ping, ssh each other. So it is definitely the router.

Comment: As I said, I'm too lazy to do the math beside any /24 or /8. If you've checked and you are in the same net, fine ... Wrong assumption from my side. - You are on a hotel. You have no access to the network or server itself ... But you want to connect over some unusual net classification. Maybe the monitoring sees there is something wrong and you shouldn't connect to that ssh server? Maybe it is filtered? Even If I wouldn't drop ICMP (ping), it is common to 'harden' systems. May a `nmap -p22 10.181.123.171` will tell us more... Even if there are reasons for such setup, I wonder why.

Comment: @LupusE its not *unusual* config. nmap shows the router and the computer itself from which you run nmap. All other hosts mysteriously appear down despite the hotel having many guests. Somehow they might have flagged my mac address and put me in a penalty box.... :-(


Question why would it work 1 night and then suddenly stop working after a few hours ? Manual intervention is less of a chance. Both computers can talk to the internet (external) but not discover each other *internally*. Can I get some 3rd party service to route my connections through ? Any idea on SOCKS / SSL tunneling ?

Comment: Glad to read, it is not an ubuntu topic. So everything further would go offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but it is possible that the IP of the server you are trying to connect to has changed: if you are working in a public-access network, it probably doesn't permanently assign internal IPs. If you can access to the server in an other way check the local IP with `ip addr show`. Quite a foolish suggestion, I know, but my experience tells me that the stupid solutions often actually is the right one.

Another possibility I cant think is some automatic upgrade to the router OS that changed some firewall settings.

Comment: pasted in above post